# Error R10 (Boot timeout) java quarkus app. The port is already set in the application settings

Tags: java, heroku, port, quarkus

[Picture with port of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhiTD.png)

Port is set like this: **quarkus.http.port=${PORT:8080}**

I have custom port on heroku from application.properties and it is use when app is running (see picture), but i have this problem  **Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch**. Who know what i need to do?

Comment: Also i trying configure port in procfile without configure in application.properties like this: web: java -Dquarkus.http.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.helper.GuildHelperApplication

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.